# Android flash vs Java

Tags: java, android

I've been thinkin about games on android and was thinking - isn't it EASIER to make a game in flash than in android using Java with android SDK ? I've only experience with Flash/AS3 and it's quite easy to create user interface, animations, layout and to write scripts.

As of Flash CS3 there are motion detection objects, so we can create really interactive games.

However I've not seen any flash game related for a phone( I mean with orientation and so ). Is there something I am missing like flash too slow on a android enabled phone?

This applies to applications too. I would like to hear opinions about Flash vs Android :)

Comment: First thing you can also create game in flash and create apk as like android.

Comment: Second thing please be clear in second third & fourth paragraph

Comment: You mean to create 2 versions of app: android + flash? If so then it's not what I've asked for. And could you specify what's wrong with my paragraphs as I really didn't understand "how to be clear". Sincerely

Comment: no you can create game in flash and adobe air will convert it in apk

Comment: Thanks, Nik! That helped for my research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create game in flash and adobe air will convert it in apk. adobeAir is version where you can create any game and just 2 or 3 step that convert it in apk.so you can publish it or play it in your android phone

Comment: That's the perfect answer which is 100% of what I was looking for but somehow missed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Flash is not supported on Android 2.1 and lower, and some manufacturers no longer provide software updates for their older devices. I think Flash will also probably be slower (which may not be an issue if your game isn't very computation/graphics heavy) and consume more battery. It also doesn't take advantage of multi-core processors right now, but that may change in the future.
On the other hand, if you write your game in Java for Android, you will be limited to one platform.
As a compromise, you could try something like Haxe, which allows you to compile your code into flash, Java and C++, among others.